# How can i add a feature like Delete for Everyone in my chat app

Tags: function, api, flutter, chat

I am making a chat app on flutter but i dont understand how to add delete for everyone feature .
any help would be great

Comment: What do you mean by delete for everyone? Delete a user's messages? That would just be a query for the user's messages and delete.

Comment: U know the feature in whatsapp or many meesaaging apps with delete for all or unsend messages label. itallows to unsend message from both side i want to implement it i my chat also

Comment: Yeah ... so you just delete a user's messages. Maybe I'm not understanding the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am under the impression that you have an API/service that handles sending/receiving messages on both ends of the chat. So, my suggestion is to add an extra parameter to your message element class that can toggle the status (thus the UI - showing 'This message has been deleted' or hiding the message altogether) of the message based on whether sender has deleted the message.

Each message would have a unique identifier, and based on this you can send a request to your server to update the status of the selected message on the receiver end.

Comment: yess i am using firebase and thanks for the help